# Horizontal Alignment Problems with Box and Column Combinations

Tags: tables, spacing, horizontal-alignment, formatting, tcolorbox

I'm creating handout sheets for the high school math classes I teach in LaTeX, having some experience using it in my undergrad, using Overleaf, and I'm struggling to get this aligned nicely. I created a 'working' solution but the alignment is bugging me and I feel there is a better way to do this. Here is the following raw LaTeX:

```
\begin{exBox}{Example \#2}
Determine the common difference of each arithmetic sequence.
\begin{multicols}{3}
    \begin{itemize}[label={}]
    \item MUST KNOW
    \item SHOULD KNOW
    \item UNDERSTANDING
    \end{itemize}    
\end{multicols}
\begin{multicols}{3}
        \begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
            \item $7,9,11,13,...$
            \item $113,106,99,92,...$
            \item $5, 6\frac{2}{3},8\frac{1}{3},10,...$
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{multicols}
    \tcbsubtitle{\centering Solutions}
    \begin{tcbitemize}[raster columns=3,raster equal height, coltitle=black,
        colframe=blue!10!white, colback=blue!10!white, fonttitle=\bfseries, frame hidden]
        \tcbitem[title={(a)}]
        \vspace{3.5cm}
        \tcbitem[squeezed title={(b)}]
        \vspace{3.5cm}
        \tcbitem[squeezed title={(c)}]
        \vspace{3.5cm}
\end{tcbitemize} 
\end{exBox}
```

and here is the exBox template created:

```
\newtcolorbox{exBox}[1]{%
    enhanced,
    title=\centering #1,
    colframe=blue!50!black,
    colback=blue!10!white,
    colbacktitle=blue!5!yellow!10!white,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    coltitle=black,
    attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-0.25mm-\tcboxedtitleheight/2,yshifttext=2mm-\tcboxedtitleheight/2},
    boxed title style={boxrule=0.5mm, 
        frame code={ \path[tcb fill frame] ([xshift=-4mm]frame.west)
        -- (frame.north west) -- (frame.north east) -- ([xshift=4mm]frame.east)
        -- (frame.south east) -- (frame.south west) -- cycle; },
        interior code={ \path[tcb fill interior] ([xshift=-2mm]interior.west)
        -- (interior.north west) -- (interior.north east)
        -- ([xshift=2mm]interior.east) -- (interior.south east) -- (interior.south west)
        -- cycle;} }
}
```

Here is a picture of the output. The goal here is get the MUST KNOW, first (a), second (a) to all align left at the same position, and the same for the center and right columns. I realize that is likely far from optimal so I'd like to see what others know about this.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...